# Different performance of ListView in Android 4.4.4 and Android 4.2.2.... How to fix it?

Tags: android, listview, focus

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>

</selector>
```

I have more than 1 ListView on the page. When moving between ListViews with Key. Last accessed ListView
remain focus when I move to next ListView.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ListView1             |    ListView2                                               |
|                       |                                                            |
|                       |                                                            |
| Menu 1                |    Content 1                                               |
| Menu 2                |    Content 2                                               |
| Menu 3                |    Content 3                                               |
| Menu 4                |    Content 4                                               |
|                       |    Content 5                                               |
|                       |    Content 6                                               |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When you use direction key in remote control(so I am developing a android project in TV), the focus change from Menu to Content:

In Android 4.4.4 platform: the selected menu(for example Menu 1) keep black, the selected Content(for example Content 1) change from white to black.updated: In other words, the Menu item stay selected when switch to Content view

In Android 4.2.2 platform: All Menu change to white, the selected Content change from white to black

How can I keep the same in two platforms? I prefer the performance in Android 4.4.2 platform.

Comment: And what about the performance actually? what performance issues are yiu having?

Comment: I want to keep the behaviour/user experience same in both versions.